# onBeginningOfSpeech() Not fired

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

This is what i tried using samples from web. As mentioned in title, Recognition Listener events are not triggered, after startListening. 
What is need is when onEndOfSpeech(), i want to play an audio file. this is done for debugging purpose. Please debug me to complete the task.

```
package com.example.speech;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*; 
import android.speech.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private SpeechRecognizer sr;
 private static final String TAG = "MyStt3Activity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void Click(View view) {

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtState);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        txt.setText("Stopped Listening");
        btn.setText("Start");
}
public void btn_Click(View view) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtState);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    if(btn.getText()=="Stop"){
        txt.setText("Stopped Listening");
        btn.setText("Start");
        sr.stopListening();
    }
    else {
        txt.setText("Listening Now");
        btn.setText("Stop");
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5);
        sr.startListening(intent);
    }
}
class listener implements RecognitionListener
{
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onReadyForSpeech");
        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onBeginningOfSpeech");
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onRmsChanged");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
    }
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onBufferReceived");
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
    }
    public void onEndOfSpeech()
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onEndofSpeech");
        Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
    }
    public void onError(int error)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onError");
        Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
        //mText.setText("error " + error);
    }
    public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onResults");
        //String str = new String();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
        //ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        //for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        //{
         //   Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
           // str += data.get(i);
        //}
        //mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));
    }
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onPartialResults");
        Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
    {
        //TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
        //state.setText("onEvent ");
          Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: The line `if(btn.getText()=="Stop")` - Have you set the text to 'Stop' in the XML. If so, this will initially return true.

Comment: yes. i have set that..

Comment: Add logging to `btn_Click` to confirm it is working?